# Register command output as 2 separate variables

Tags: bash, powershell, ansible

I have an Ansible playbook that runs a script over my remote machines.
The script finds log files, determine the application the log file came from (so it would know the destination directory), and uploads the files back to the Ansible server (using scp).

Just because it worth mentioning - there are 2 different playbooks, one for Windows servers, using a PowerShell script, and the other is for Linux servers, using a bash script.

I would like to eliminate the scp part for those scripts, and instead using the fetch module in my playbooks. But I'm facing a problem with that - my scripts generates 2 variables for each application on each server:

1. the log file, full path.
2. the destination directory in the Ansible server (determined by the servers name and the application name).

My current playbook looks like that (this is the Windows one):

```yaml
---

- hosts: <WindowsHosts>
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
   - name: Find and Copy Windows Applications Logs
     script: fetchwinFindLogs.ps1 {{ server_partition }} {{days}} {{ansibleSRV_Port}} {{ansibleSRV_IP}}
     register: result
   - debug:
       var: result

#   - fetch: src={{ result }} dest={{ result }}
#     with_items: "{{ result.stdout_lines }}"
```

The output:

```
PLAY [<WinHost>] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Find and Copy Windows Applications Logs] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [<WinHost>]

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [<WinHost>] => {
    "result": {
        "changed": true,
        "failed": false,
        "rc": 0,
        "stderr": "",
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "stdout": "C:\\<Maindir>\\<App1>\\Logs\\platform.log.2020-09-18\r\n/<LinuxMainDir>/<logs>/Applications/<serverName>.<App1>/\r\nC:\\<Maindir>\\<App2>\\Logs\\platform.log.2020-09-18\r\n/<LinuxMainDir>/<logs>/Applications/<serverName>.<App2>/\r\nC:\\<Maindir>\\<App3>\\Logs\\platform.log.2020-09-18\r\n/<LinuxMainDir>/<logs>/Applications/<serverName>.<App3>/\r\nC:\\<Maindir>\\<App4>\\Logs\\platform.log.2020-09-18\r\n/<LinuxMainDir>/<logs>/Applications/<serverName>.<App4>/\r\n",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "C:\\<Maindir>\\<App1>\\Logs\\platform.log.2020-09-18",
            "/<LinuxMainDir>/<logs>/Applications/<serverName>.<App1>/",
            "C:\\<Maindir>\\<App2>\\Logs\\platform.log.2020-09-18",
            "/<LinuxMainDir>/<logs>/Applications/<serverName>.<App2>/",
            "C:\\<Maindir>\\<App3>\\Logs\\platform.log.2020-09-18",
            "/<LinuxMainDir>/<logs>/Applications/<serverName>.<App3>/",
            "C:\\<Maindir>\\<App4>\\Logs\\platform.log.2020-09-18",
            "/<LinuxMainDir>/<logs>/Applications/<serverName>.<App4>/"
        ]
    }
}

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
<WinHost>                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

How do I use the 2 separate values gotten from the script, so the fetch module would know to direct each log file from each application to the correct directory in my Ansible server?

This includes, of course, looping over every 2 values, so it would direct the correct log to the correct destination directory (since, again, the first value will always be the full path log, and the second would be the destination directory, for each application separately).

Answer (score 0):

There is possibly plenty of ways to achieve this.

Here are two of them:

1. Using the [extended loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#extended-loop-variables) variables and a `when` condition, you could skip every other item with a `when` and a modulo `%` and get the `item` along with the `ansible_loop.nextitem`.
   Here is an example for that:

   ```yaml
   - hosts: all
     gather_facts: no

     tasks:
       - debug: 
           msg: 
             - "src: {{ item  }}"
             - "dest: {{ ansible_loop.nextitem  }}"
         loop: "{{ result.stdout_lines }}"
         when: ansible_loop.index % 2 == 1
         loop_control:
           extended: yes
         vars:
           result:
             stdout_lines:
               - "C:\\<Maindir>\\<App1>\\Logs\\platform.log.2020-09-18"
               - "/<LinuxMainDir>/<logs>/Applications/<serverName>.<App1>/"
               - "C:\\<Maindir>\\<App2>\\Logs\\platform.log.2020-09-18"
               - "/<LinuxMainDir>/<logs>/Applications/<serverName>.<App2>/"
               - "C:\\<Maindir>\\<App3>\\Logs\\platform.log.2020-09-18"
               - "/<LinuxMainDir>/<logs>/Applications/<serverName>.<App3>/"
               - "C:\\<Maindir>\\<App4>\\Logs\\platform.log.2020-09-18"
               - "/<LinuxMainDir>/<logs>/Applications/<serverName>.<App4>/"
   ```

   This yields the recap:

   ```
   PLAY [all] ********************************************************************************************************

   TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************
   ok: [localhost] => (item=C:\<Maindir>\<App1>\Logs\platform.log.2020-09-18) => {
       "msg": [
           "src: C:\\<Maindir>\\<App1>\\Logs\\platform.log.2020-09-18",
           "dest: /<LinuxMainDir>/<logs>/Applications/<serverName>.<App1>/"
       ]
   }
   skipping: [localhost] => (item=/<LinuxMainDir>/<logs>/Applications/<serverName>.<App1>/) 
   ok: [localhost] => (item=C:\<Maindir>\<App2>\Logs\platform.log.2020-09-18) => {
       "msg": [
           "src: C:\\<Maindir>\\<App2>\\Logs\\platform.log.2020-09-18",
           "dest: /<LinuxMainDir>/<logs>/Applications/<serverName>.<App2>/"
       ]
   }
   skipping: [localhost] => (item=/<LinuxMainDir>/<logs>/Applications/<serverName>.<App2>/) 
   ok: [localhost] => (item=C:\<Maindir>\<App3>\Logs\platform.log.2020-09-18) => {
       "msg": [
           "src: C:\\<Maindir>\\<App3>\\Logs\\platform.log.2020-09-18",
           "dest: /<LinuxMainDir>/<logs>/Applications/<serverName>.<App3>/"
       ]
   }
   skipping: [localhost] => (item=/<LinuxMainDir>/<logs>/Applications/<serverName>.<App3>/) 
   ok: [localhost] => (item=C:\<Maindir>\<App4>\Logs\platform.log.2020-09-18) => {
       "msg": [
           "src: C:\\<Maindir>\\<App4>\\Logs\\platform.log.2020-09-18",
           "dest: /<LinuxMainDir>/<logs>/Applications/<serverName>.<App4>/"
       ]
   }
   skipping: [localhost] => (item=/<LinuxMainDir>/<logs>/Applications/<serverName>.<App4>/) 

   PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
   localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
   ```
2. Another idea would be to use Python [array slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=slice#slice) to separate odd from even elements and Ansible [`zip`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#zip-and-zip-longest-filters) filter.
   This would be the playbook:

   ```yaml
   - hosts: all
     gather_facts: no

     tasks:
       - debug: 
           msg: 
             - "src: {{ item.0 }}"
             - "dest: {{ item.1 }}"
         loop: "{{ result.stdout_lines[::2] | zip(result.stdout_lines[1::2]) | list }}"
         vars:
           result:
             stdout_lines:
               - "C:\\<Maindir>\\<App1>\\Logs\\platform.log.2020-09-18"
               - "/<LinuxMainDir>/<logs>/Applications/<serverName>.<App1>/"
               - "C:\\<Maindir>\\<App2>\\Logs\\platform.log.2020-09-18"
               - "/<LinuxMainDir>/<logs>/Applications/<serverName>.<App2>/"
               - "C:\\<Maindir>\\<App3>\\Logs\\platform.log.2020-09-18"
               - "/<LinuxMainDir>/<logs>/Applications/<serverName>.<App3>/"
               - "C:\\<Maindir>\\<App4>\\Logs\\platform.log.2020-09-18"
               - "/<LinuxMainDir>/<logs>/Applications/<serverName>.<App4>/"
   ```

   This yields the recap:

   ```
   PLAY [all] ********************************************************************************************************

   TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************
   ok: [localhost] => (item=['C:\\<Maindir>\\<App1>\\Logs\\platform.log.2020-09-18', '/<LinuxMainDir>/<logs>/Applications/<serverName>.<App1>/']) => {
       "msg": [
           "src: C:\\<Maindir>\\<App1>\\Logs\\platform.log.2020-09-18",
           "dest: /<LinuxMainDir>/<logs>/Applications/<serverName>.<App1>/"
       ]
   }
   ok: [localhost] => (item=['C:\\<Maindir>\\<App2>\\Logs\\platform.log.2020-09-18', '/<LinuxMainDir>/<logs>/Applications/<serverName>.<App2>/']) => {
       "msg": [
           "src: C:\\<Maindir>\\<App2>\\Logs\\platform.log.2020-09-18",
           "dest: /<LinuxMainDir>/<logs>/Applications/<serverName>.<App2>/"
       ]
   }
   ok: [localhost] => (item=['C:\\<Maindir>\\<App3>\\Logs\\platform.log.2020-09-18', '/<LinuxMainDir>/<logs>/Applications/<serverName>.<App3>/']) => {
       "msg": [
           "src: C:\\<Maindir>\\<App3>\\Logs\\platform.log.2020-09-18",
           "dest: /<LinuxMainDir>/<logs>/Applications/<serverName>.<App3>/"
       ]
   }
   ok: [localhost] => (item=['C:\\<Maindir>\\<App4>\\Logs\\platform.log.2020-09-18', '/<LinuxMainDir>/<logs>/Applications/<serverName>.<App4>/']) => {
       "msg": [
           "src: C:\\<Maindir>\\<App4>\\Logs\\platform.log.2020-09-18",
           "dest: /<LinuxMainDir>/<logs>/Applications/<serverName>.<App4>/"
       ]
   }

   PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
   localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
   ```

When I would have a slight preference for the second approach, I could understand it could be less readable for people not used to Python's array slicing.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I assign the output of the script to the loop? it looks like you just added the output to the playbook itself.

Comment: Oh ok, I see you trouble. `register: result` on your first task means you create a new variable called, in your case, `return` (so, in your words, you you assign it to `return`). You are not forced to call it `return` though, name it as you like: e.g. `register: logs_path_and_dest` would  later be usable in a loop this way: `loop: {{ logs_path_and_dest.output }}`. So, yes, in my case I hardcoded the variable, but with the exact same name and dictionary structure as yours. So you can just use the `loop` syntax as in the answer.

Comment: Registering a variable documentation page is [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables), by the way.